# Asp.NET OnMouseOver and OnMouseOut clientside

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I hope someone can give me a hint about what should I do in this case. I want to show a notification email. I have a timer that fires passing a time. If someone mouseover the linkbutton then will show all the emails and if out then dissapears. The fact is when I am trying to select one of the emails the content (which has the emails) dessapears because of the mouseout. What should I do to avoid this? Thanks in advance!!! by the way I get my emails at onmouseover and close on out.

```
    <asp:Timer ID="TimerNew" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="TimerNew_Tick" Enabled="false"></asp:Timer>
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelTools" runat="server" >
            <div runat="server" id="DropDownMenu">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton" runat="server" onmouseover="OnClientMouseOver()" onmouseout="OnClientMouseOut()">
                </asp:LinkButton>
                <div id="divEmails" runat="server">
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <ul id="emailList" runat="server">
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>

Here is my javascript function.

function OnClientMouseOver(obj, event)
{
    var isOpen = '<%= this.Open %>';
    if (isOpen == false)
    {
        __doPostBack('OpenEmails');
    }
}

function OnClientMouseOut(obj, event)
{
    var isOpen = '<%= this.Open %>';
    var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
    if (e.parentNode == this || e == this)
    {
        return;
    }
    __doPostBack('CloseEmails');
}
```

this.Open is a variable (viewstate to dont lose it). I use telerik RadAjaxProxyManager, I do an ajax postback and execute my server methods.

Comment: I think you need to show your JavaScript functions for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: @user2343003: did you try to use the mouse out for the popup which shows the emails. Else, try by giving a timedelay in the `OnClientMouseOut(..)`.